# How to pass data from frontend jQuery to backend node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I sent the <%=searchString%> to the frontend at the first place.
Then, I trying to add a sort function on my search page.
How can I get the searchString value send back to my backend when redo the search with a sorting function.

node.js segment code

```js
router.get('/search', function(req, res){
 console.log("Searching " + JSON.stringify(req.query));
    var results = [];
    for(var i in restaurants) {
        for(var j in restaurants[i]["categories"]) {
            var category = restaurants[i]["categories"][j];
            if(req.query.q && req.query.q.indexOf(category) != -1) {
                results.push({
                    name: restaurants[i]["name"],
                    price: restaurants[i]["priceCat"],
                    categories: restaurants[i]["categories"]
                });
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Search Results: " + JSON.stringify(results));
 res.render('pages/search', {
        pageTitle: "search",
        searchString: req.query.q,
        results : results
    });
});
```

```html
<%- contentFor('body') %>
<h1>Search Results: <small><%=searchString%></small></h1>
<% if (results.length === 0) { %>
  <h4>No results found</h4>  
<% } else { %>
  <h2><small>Sort by:</small>
  <div class="row-sm-1">
        <form action="/search" method="GET">
          <div class="form-group">
            <a href="/search">
              <button type="submit" name="price" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Price</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </h2>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Category</th>
    </tr>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {%>
      <tr>
        <td><%= results[i].name%></td>
        <td><%= results[i].price%></td>
        <td>
          <% for(var j = 0; j < results[i].categories.length; j++) {%>
            <%= results[i].categories[j]%><% if(j != results[i].categories.length - 1) {%>,<%}%>
          <%}%>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <%}%>
  <%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: The same way as you would with any backend. It has nothing to do with NodeJS. you can use $.get or $.post in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $.post in jquery to hit the route defined in node.js/express.js in your case.

I think you're missing the basic mind mapping about the architectural style. REST architecture can be used for this task.

Explanation on REST : [What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

This would help to get the basic idea as well

[image]